# What is the working domain of the lambda function?

Tags: c++

```
{
... ...
std::function<int()> action;
    switch (A)
    {
    case 0:
        action = []()->int
        {
            return 1;
        };
        break;
    case 1:
        action = []()->int
        {
            return 2;
        };
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
... ...
}
```

Above is the code, would the lambda function pointed to by the functional pointer still be alive outside the switch-case?

An extra question is how do lambda function gets recycled? If I were to use `std::move()` like below, would the lambda function unable to be automatically recycled/deconstructed at end of `funct()`?

```
void funct(){
... ...
std::function<int()> action;
    switch (A)
    {
    case 0:
        action = std::move([]()->int
        {
            return 1;
        });
        break;
    case 1:
        action = std::move([]()->int
        {
            return 2;
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
... ...
}
```

Comment: `action` stores a *copy* of the lambda function.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  so is functional class or pointer?

Comment: @DavisHerring oops, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. "Class or pointer" makes no sense. Pointers are things. Classes are kinds of things. A lambda function is an object. `std::function` stores a copy of that object. There are no user-visible pointers involved. No, you don't need `std::move`, it achieves absolutely nothing at all, the original code is perfectly fine as is.

Answer (score 2):

So we can simplify the question a bunch, the same question could be asked of this code:

```
std::function<int()> action;
{
    action = std::move([]()->int  {
        return 1;
    });
}
```

in this case you basically have this:

```
Type default_init_value_type;
{
    default_init_value_type = SomeConvertableType{};
}
```

So what is happening is essentially you are converting the type and copying the lambda *object* into the `std::function`. The original temporary object will be destroyed as normal. Since the compiler chooses how to implement the std library and lambda (under the conditions of the standard) how this is implemented and what get destroyed will likely depend on the compiler.

As for your second example. The `std::move` here does nothing. Your type is already an r-value, so `std::move` (which is really just a cast to an r-value type) has no effect.

Comment: Sometimes `std::move` applied to a prvalue is *counter*productive!